# How to switch to different JRE in command line from teamcity

Tags: teamcity

My teamcity build configuration uses Java8 but for one of my command line I have to switch to Java7 . How can I achieve this in a command line Teamcity step.

Thanks for suggestions in advance

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your command line step in a shell script. In the shell script , change the JAVA_HOME and PATH variables to point to JRE7 instead of JRE8, as required

It would be of the form

```
export JAVA_HOME=<path for java>
export PATH=<path for java bin>:$PATH
```